# Advance concepts of Symfony2, that should I learn before start my bundles?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I have 1+ year experience in symfony2,now I want to make my own base bundles to start my all new projects with these bundles,so my questions are ...

1) What I should have to know to start my own bundles ?

2) What should I do to make these bundles publicly available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommand you to know more about Composer.
This is the most important part of the Symfony's community.

When you have a ready Bundle that you want to be shared, you have 3 things to do :

- Create a public repository (a GitHub repository for instance)
- Add a composer.json at root path, so you can declare your Bundle name, settings, AND DEPENDENCIES
- Declare your Bundle to https://packagist.org/

You may also do make the community aware that you did great job by :

- Adding some doc to your Bundle (you will never install a Bundle that does not have documentation)
- Adding some automated testing, using an open CI platform (like https://travis-ci.org/)

Then, you are all set.